# I want to call the same key in all arrays from a JSON that I'm pulling from an API. Something like API_Source["data"][1..4]. How can I do this?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, api

Here is my current code where I'm using the API to seed a database.

```
@games.each do |game|
    Game.create(
        local_team: @games["data"][0]["visitorTeam"]["data"]["name"],
        away_team: @games["data"][0]["localTeam"]["data"]["name"]);
    end
```

I can go through, one by one, and just increase the "[0]" one line at a time, but that would make for a wall of syntax.

How can I call something like "[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]", etc?

Here's what @games looks like in JSON

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "localTeam": {
                "data": {
                    "name": "Celtic",
                }
            },
            "visitorTeam": {
                "data": {
                    "name": "Rangers",
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "localTeam": {
                "data": {
                    "name": "Rangers", 
                }
            },
            "visitorTeam": {
                "data": {
                    "name": "Hearts",
                }
            }
        },
```

This continues for another 10 matches. I want to call around a few hundred so you can imagine why I'd want to streamline this.

Comment: Bit confusing that you're doing `@games.each do |game|` but not using `game` inside the block. What does `@games` really look like? Are you sure you shouldn't be doing `@games['data'].each do |game|` and then using `game` to create your Games?

Comment: I tried `@games['data'].each do |game|` and got hit with `"TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer"`. @games is what I've named the JSON response I'm getting from the API.

Comment: @muistooshort I added what the JSON looks like in the original question.

Comment: You'd do `@games['data'].each do |game|` and then look at `game['localTeam']['data']['name']` inside the iterator, similarly for `visitorTeam`.

Comment: @muistooshort I've been trying to figure this out all day and just adding "game" in the iterator completely did it for me. You're a hero!